# How to convert a directory of XML files in to RRD Files

Tags: linux, xml, bash, rrdtool

I need to restore rrd files from my exisiting xml files. So I have used following simple bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in /home/dump_xml/*.xml;
do
rrdtool restore $i /home/rrd_new/"${i%.xml}".rrd;
done
```

I could not execute following script due to this error,

```
ERROR: Could not create xml reader for: /home/dump_xml/*.xml
```

But I could restore files one by one. Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: It means that there are no files with name ending in `.rrd` inside `~/dump_xml`. But even if they are, your _rrdtool_ command looks odd: It would expand into something like `rrdtool restora /home/dump_xml/foo.rrd /home/rrd_new/home/dump_xml/foo.rrd.xml`, which is perhaps not what you want.

Comment: @user1934428 I am really sorry I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use:

```
for i in /home/dump_xml/*.xml
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

You will see that $i equals:

- /home/dump_xml/a.xml
- /home/dump_xml/b.xml

You see, it contains the path.  Therefore your `rddtool` will try to write the results in `/home/dump_xml/home/dump_xml/a.rrd`.

You have to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in xml/*.xml
do
    filename=$(basename "$i")
    rrdtool restore "$i" /home/rrd_new/"${filename%.xml}".rrd;
done
```

Do not forget to double-quote your variable extensions.

Comment: I would do a `basename "$i" .xml`. so that `filename` already doesn't have an extension. You then don't have to remove the extension afterwards.

Comment: ah ah, very nice, I did not know about the extension part of `basename`, thanks!